# Break a given MATLAB string into array of sections

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following string:

```
%%
a = 2
%% 
a =3
%%
t = 0:.1:pi*4;
y = sin(t);
for k = 3:2:9
    %%
    y = y + sin(k*t)/k;
    if ~mod(k,3)
        %%
        display(sprintf('When k = %.1f',k));
        plot(t,y)
    end
end
```

If you notice the third section has nested sections.

I want the output to be

```
[ 'a = 2', 'a=3' , 't = 0:.1:pi*4; y = sin(t); for k = 3:2:9 %% y = y + sin(k*t)/k; if ~mod(k,3) %% display(sprintf('When k = %.1f',k)); plot(t,y) end end']
```

How can achieve this using string manipulation?

The problem is using normal regex with '%%' will break the 3rd section into 3 sections.

Comment: So a section is defined by a `%%` on the start of the line? That would be easy enough to put into a regex, simply use `^` to match the start of a line.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this? I.e. what are the critieria for creating one 'combined' section?

Comment: What is your final motivation? Matlab is not a reflective language, which means that it will probably be hard to manipulate matlab statements with matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the logic behind this is that you want to keep any loops or conditional statements (`for`, `while`, and `if`) together, then you can check for '%%' but also track the number of loops/conditionals you enter and exit.

If you are going through this line by line, then the code would look like this (where the variable `tline` is the line of text):

```
% initialize counters
str_count = 0;
in_loop = 0;

% iterate through text lines
while (tline ~= -1)
    % check for the %% marker but only increment string counter if not in a loop
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'%%')) && (in_loop == 0);
        str_count = str_count + 1;
    else
        % if no %% or in a loop, add the current line to the current string
        str_set{str_count} = [str_set{str_count} tline];

        % check for "for", "if", or "while" and increment the loop counter if found
        if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'for ')) || ~isempty(strfind(tline,'if ')) || ~isempty(strfind(tline,'while '))
            in_loop = in_loop + 1;
        end
        % check for "end" and decrement the loop counter if found
        if ~isempty(strfind(tline,'end'));
            in_loop = in_loop - 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Keep in mind that this uses `strfind` to look for the `for`, `while`, `if`, and `end` commands (with spaces after the first three). However, it would also pick up words that had those strings at the end (for example, the line `xfor = 1;` would be picked up). So you either have to add some extra checks or be careful about how you name the variables -- perhaps a better way of looking for those strings is the best. You should see spaces before the words unless they are the first words, and could add conditions to that effect.